# React Native: Facebook permissions are always declined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, facebook-javascript-sdk, react-redux

So I am trying to use `redux` together with the `react-native-fbsdk` package to login a user, but no mather how I go about it, the permissions always gets denied, even after granting them in the login screen. The console logs can be seen below:

[image: Console logs]

Here you see my action for the authFailure:

```
export function authFailure(authError) {
  return {
    type: AUTH_FAILURE,
    action.authError.message
  }
}
```

Here is the function that gets executed onPress dispatching the action `authStarted()` and then calling the function `_fbAuthAPI()` which handles the fbsdk. This can be seen below this one.

```
export function _fbAuth() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(authStarted())
    const values = []
    _fbAuthAPI().then((result) => {
      values.concat(result.accessToken)
      return _getUserInformationAPI(result.accessToken)
    }).then((profile) => {
      values.concat(profile)
      dispatch(authSuccess(...values))
    }).catch((error) => {
      dispatch(authFailure(error))
      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(authFailureRemove())
      }, 4000)
    })
  }
}

export function _fbAuthAPI() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then((result) => {
      if (result.isCancelled) {
        throw new Error('Login was cancelled')
      } else if (result.declinedPermissions) {
        throw new Error('Permissions were declined')
      } else {
        return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
      }
    }).then((result) => {
      resolve(result)
    }).catch((error) => {
      reject(error)
    })
  })
}
```

As for the reducer:

```
export default function authReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AUTH_STARTED:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        authenticating: true
      })
      break
    case AUTH_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        authenticating: false,
        authError: false,
        facebookToken: facebookToken,
        facebookProfile: facebookProfile
      })
      break
    case AUTH_FAILURE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        authenticating: false,
        authError: authError
      })
      break
      ...
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

**Setup:**

- React Native 0.45.1
- React Native FBSDK "^0.6.1"
- Redux "^3.7.1"
- MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, so I managed to solve the issue.
Basically, the when you call `declinedPermissions` on the result from the `logInWithReadPermissions` it always returns true, as it is an array.. Then, even if you dont have any declined permissions, it takes it as true.

The simple way to get around it, is just to see whats in the array and determine what to do based on that:

```
// Returns an empty array, therefore evaluates to true
  if (result.declinedPermissions) {
    throw new Error('Permissions were declined')
  }

// The first index of the array is empty
  if (result.declinedPermissions[0] === "") {
    throw new Error('Permissions were declined')
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't help with the Facebook SDK and authentication, but the authError being undefined is because in this section, authError is truly undefined

```
case AUTH_FAILURE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        authenticating: false,
        authError: authError   // Where is this coming from?
      })
      break
```

I think what you intended to have there is `authError: action.authError`

Comment: I figured that one out as well - but thanks for it!
It is however the Facebook SDK part that I am truly lost in.